# Get parent ID from div jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a image inside a div when i click on the image i want it to alert me of the parent id that will be "group1"

```
<div id="group1">
<img class="header_logo_dis" src="test.png">
</div>

$('.header_logo_dis').click(function() {
    alert($(this).parent("div:first"));
});
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How about:

```
alert( $(this).closest('div').attr('id') );
```

Comment: @Gully, if that isn't working you are doing some thing else wrong,

Comment: YEAHH, you made my day! Thank you, that is exactly what i am searching for!

Answer (score 19):

Or to be extra efficient and skip jQuery altogether:

```
alert(this.parentNode.id);
```

Comment: I'd +1 if I had any more votes left today. Using jQuery for EVERYTHING is really unhealthy.

Comment: I've got a +1 for you. This is how I'd do it. *Much* better performance.

Comment: @patrick I was sceptical about this method having "much" better performance. so I made a little testbench here http://vidasp.net/tinydemos/jQuery-vs-native.html The results are: jQuery  ~190ms, Native ~3ms. Amazing!

Comment: @Šime Vidas - Yes, it doesn't really stand a chance against two simple and direct property lookups.

Comment: +1  but it is returning "(an empty string)" in console why is that? i have a valid id though

Comment: @manny Could be various reasons. This probably isn't the best place to explore them – try asking your own question or taking it to chat.

Answer (score 1):

```
alert ($(this).parent().attr('id'));
```